# No Load DataGridView from mysql BBDD vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I want to show a table of my database, after this code worked but now does not work and i dont know because it doesn't work...

when load this form I don't see any table... sorry a I need help...
Where do can be wrong?

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class inicio
Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection

Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
Dim updatecommand As New MySqlCommand
Dim deletecommand As New MySqlCommand
Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim myData As New DataTable
Dim SQL As String


Private Sub inicio_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection()

    ' Define the SQL to grab data from table.

    SQL = "SELECT * FROM compras"

    'Connection String

    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;" _
    & "user id=root;" _
    & "password=;" _
    & "database=comerciojuegos"

    ' Try, Catch, Finally
    Try

        MysqlConn.Open()

        myCommand.Connection = MysqlConn
        myCommand.CommandText = SQL

        myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand

        myAdapter.Fill(myData)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = myData

        'updatecommand = New MySqlCommand("update compras set id_compra=@id_compra,id_comprador=@id_comprador,id_producto=@id_producto,fecha_compra=@fecha_compra,detalles_compra=@detalles_compra where (id_compra=@id_compra)", MysqlConn)
        'updatecommand.Parameters.Add("@id_compra", MySqlDbType.Int16, 50, "id_compra")
        'updatecommand.Parameters.Add("@id_comprador", MySqlDbType.Int16, 50, "id_comprador")
        'updatecommand.Parameters.Add("@id_producto", MySqlDbType.Int16, 50, "id_producto")
        'updatecommand.Parameters.Add("@fecha_compra", MySqlDbType.Date, 50, "fecha_compra")
        'updatecommand.Parameters.Add("@detalles_compra", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "detalles_compra")
        'myAdapter.UpdateCommand = updatecommand

        DataGridView1.Refresh()

    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to database: " & myerror.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Close()
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you trace? Do you get rows in the datatable?

Comment: I don' get any rows in my data table... This is a problem ..

Comment: If you get no rows, then either your connection is not working or your table select is wrong or your table is empty.